# Multiplying two large integer values gives incorrect result

Tags: java

This method is for getting (By input from user) the two largest Integers in the given data set and calculates their product. It works well for every input until I tried the array of two integers `100000` and `90000` where it returns `410065408`.

This is my Java method:

```
static int getMaxPairwiseProduct(int[] numbers) {
    int max=0,lessermax=0;
    int n = numbers.length;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        //if(j==k)continue;
        if(numbers[j]>0 && numbers[j]>=max) {               
            lessermax=max;max=numbers[j];
            System.out.println(j);//k=j;
        } else if(numbers[j]>lessermax) {      
            lessermax=numbers[j];
            System.out.println(j);}
        }
    //result=;
    return max*lessermax;
}
```

This is my `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //FastScanner scanner = new FastScanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] numbers = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    scanner.close();
    System.out.println(getMaxPairwiseProduct(numbers));
}
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with Scanner, but with size of `int` and how it can overflow. You would get same results regardless if you fill `int[]` array using values from Scanner or by hardcoding them directly in array like `new int[]{100000,90000}`.

Comment: i tried to edit my question that i already switched from int to double and long but the same result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's overflowing the capacity of `int` and wrapping around. `100000 * 90000` is `9000000000`. The maximum positive value of an `int` is 2^31-1, which is `2147483647` (a bit less than quarter of `9000000000`).

If you want the product of those two numbers, you'll need to use `long` instead.

```
100000L * 90000L = 9000000000L = 0x218711a00L
```

For 32 bit data type, anything outside the 32 bits (8 hex digits) is chopped off because of overflow. So the value that remains is: `0x18711a00` == `410065408`

Comment: i tried to edit my question that i already switched from int to double and long but the same result because that the user may not know how to enter long values

Comment: @AbderrahmanEcherif: The user doesn't have to do anything special to enter long values, you just have to read them with `nextLong` instead of `nextInt`. If you do that, and use `long` instead of `int`, you'll be able to multiply those two numbers.

Comment: @Andreas: Doh! I kept looking at my original number thinking "It just doesn't look right." but it didn't click. Thanks!

Comment: @AbderrahmanEcherif: I didn't look at the algorithm. I looked at the issue raised by the question: That 100000 * 90000 gives you an odd result.

Comment: @ T.J. Crowder thank you very very much i was just a bit perplexed and my computer too slow  it works very well now thanks a lot